# Extending holomorphic connections

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $D$ denote the disk $|z|<1$ in the complex plane and $U=D\0$(punctured disk). Define a holomorphic connection $\nabla$ on $\mathscr{O}_U$ by $\nabla(1)=\exp{(-1/z)}$. Does this extend to a logarithmic connection on $\mathscr{O}_D$, i.e. does this extend to $\nabla_D:\mathscr{O}_D\to \Omega_D(0)$?

More generally, suppose $\nabla$ is a holomorphic connection on $\mathscr{O}_U^{\oplus r}$, can we extend it to a logarithmic connection on $\mathscr{O}_D^{\oplus r}$.

Answer (score 3):

Connections on the punctured disk extend (up to isomorphism) to connections with log poles, but not in general to holomorphic connections.

A standard reference is:
Pierre Deligne. "Equations differentielles a points singuliers reguliers. Springer-Verlag,
Berlin, 1970. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 163.

I'd say the key point is that in one dimension the connection is integrable corresponds to a local system defined by its monodromy - an $r\times r$ matrix A, which will have a logarithm.

Perhaps someone else can suggest a more recent exposition.

Comment: The book Isomonodromic deformations and Frobenius manifolds by Sabbah
deals with that. 